# If the user selects a row in a JTreeTable SwingX, how do I find out which node is actually selected

Tags: java, swingx, treetable

I am working on TreeTable in swingx library and I cant find a way how to actually get the treetable node selected on view. There is a method called getSelected, but it only gets the index from the table, I have no means to translate it into the model, plus this index depends if the node expanded or not.
And in the model there are not methods to get children by the index on the table, and again the index depends if nodes are expanded or not, so I can't see no sure way to get actual selected node from the table.
Did anyone have the same problem and can help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't the method

```
getPathForRow(...)
```

give you what you need?

Comment: and what can i do with this path? does it depends if rows expand or not? what can i do with the path when i get it?

Comment: Well, the last object in the array held in the path corresponds to the selected node, so it does not matter whether some nodes are collapsed. Once you get the object for the node, you can do whatever you want then, given you know the class of the node.

Comment: never mind, i figured it out. thanks for the answer, it worked well for me